# how to download java from terminal with login

Tags: java, authentication, download

I was trying to download jdk 8 (tar.gz) from oracle via terminal. It is giving error 401(not authorised) error as asking to login to oracle site to download. How can I do that via terminal?

I'm using the command: wget -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" /url/copied/from/oracle

To be specific: `wget -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u211-b12/478a62b7d4e34b78b671c754eaaf38ab/jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Comment: They've changed the license; you can no longer do this.

Comment: so how can I download the tar file then ?